# Why is the "edit" link grayed out in some, but not all posts?

Tags: support, editing, user-interface

Why are some of the "edit" links on some questions active and others not?

[image: edit 1]

[image: edit 2]

Comment: It happens when edit queue for that question is full (pending peer review).

Comment: To see review queue you need enough reputation. For now suggestive edits are being review by the owner of the post or SE mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The reason for "edit" link disabled are-
>
> - A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the last day. You are banned for a week.
> - We are out of empty slots in the queue.
> - There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.
> - You are not logged on and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
>
> For full summary read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

For your case it appears to be the second point.

Comment: @Skippy the suggested edit disabled link isn't even a private beta issue.  You'll see this on every site, but there are normally enough 2K users (or the 500 rep equivalent in beta sites) to approve edits that they don't stick around too long.  You are now 1 of 2 people who can approve edits now so it is all up to you :-)